# How can I concatenate data from a few files of one package in Golang?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, package

For example, structure:

```
 /src
   main.go
   /test
     test1.go
     test2.go
```

, main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./test"
) 

func main(){
    fmt.Println(test.A)
}
```

test1.go:

```
package test

var A  = []int{1,2,3}
```

test2.go:

```
package test

var A = []int{3,7}
```

I understand, that it's a wrong code, it throws the error, because I'm redeclaring the variable. I just want to ask, which way should I go to concatenate this same-name variables from files of one package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initiate the slice and the append to it using the `init()` functions :

*test1.go:*

```
package test

var A  = []int{}

func appendA(v ...int) {
   A = append(A, v...)
   sort.Ints(A) // sort to make deterministic order per @peterSO comment
}

func init() {
   appendA(1, 2)
}
```

*test2.go:*

```
package test

func init() {
   appendA(3, 4)
}
```

Comment: Close, but you probably want `append(A, 1, 2)` -- `A` isn't a `[][]int` slice.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Corrected, I always forget that.

Comment: The result is not deterministic, either `[1 2 3 4]` or `[3 4 1 2]`. [Package initialization](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization): "... calling all init functions in the order they appear in the source, possibly in multiple files, as presented to the compiler."

Comment: @peterSO Is right, if the order matters you need to build slice in some other way, maybe you can implement the sorting interface for the slice type and sort it after each initiation.

Comment: @EmilDavtyan: See my answer for a simple deterministic solution.

Comment: @peterSO Yes, I saw it. I just thought I provide a little more pluggable approach where a file's initiation is self contained.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

`test1.go`:

```
package test

var A []int

func init() {
    A = append(a1, a2...)
}

var a1 = []int{1, 2, 3}
```

`test2.go`:

```
package test

var a2 = []int{3, 7}
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "test"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test.A)
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 3 7]
```